# .NET WinForms How to resize parent when child controls get bigger

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, resize

Win forms problem.

I have the following structure

```
Form
-> User Control
-> -> Panel
-> -> -> GridViewControl
```

When the grid view control adds a new row, the user control does not resize.  I would like the user control to resize (and the panel as well ) to accommodate the increasing sized grid control.

Is there a way to configure properties to do this?  Or do I need to do something programmatic?

I am thinking I may have to learn how to use delegates and notify the parent that the child control has resized so it can respond appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

Particularly I recomend you to just use scroll bars and avoid a bigger form, but whatever, you can just use the ControlAdded or the SizeChanged event of GridView or DataGridView. You really have to learn about delegates and events.

So inside the event, just check the count of itens and resize as you want.

Comment: I tried `SizeChanged`, `AutoSizeChanged`, and `ClientSizeChanged` but none were triggered when new data added to the grid.  I had to use `RowsAdded`; any better suggestions?